# Issues Merging two C# GUI classes with GIT

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio

I'm working with a group on a programming assignment and we are tasked with merging our created classes into master. All the classes have merged just fine except for one team member and I's classes. Currently my GUI class (the first one the user will see) is merged into `master` along with the other group members non GUI classes. But we are having issues merging my GUI and the other Team member's GUI.

I can run master (with only my GUI) and it works as expected; user sees my form and can do stuff. Our main looks like

```
static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new MyForm());
        }
```

Now, our other team member with his gui branched off master before I had my code set up and his form/ branch is ran the same way (and it works). So I believe the issue lies in that we are confusing Visual Studio with what the "main" GUI is. My GUI takes user input and does stuff with it and then hides itself and the the other team member's GUI is supposed to be shown.

What are we missing here? Are we not allowed to call `Run()` on just one GUI and then basically call `OtherGui.show()` on the other? What is that is going awry when trying to merge these two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the merge issue was. It was not necessarily the line `Application.Run(new MyForm());` that was the explicit issue, what the main issue was, was that in the `project.csproj` file under the `<ItemGroup>` tag, I simply needed to manually copy in the `<EmbeddedResource>` tag for the other GUI and also the corresponding `<compile>` tags that pertained also to the other GUI.

When trying to do a merge it was trying to stuff the contents of each GUI's `<compile>` all under one tag. Manually separating them in the merge window fixed the issue.